# error:no such coloumn while getting media files

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

in my music player i want to get songs from album,but it gives me error in the logs.please explain me this error why this occurs.i saw all the previous question on stackoverflow about this problem but couldnt understand,please help.

```
 public void getAlbumsLists() {
        final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
        _id = MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID;
        final String album_name = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM;
        final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ARTIST;
        tracks = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS;
        final String data=MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
        final String id1=MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
        final String tit=MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
        final String nam=MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME;
        final String typ=MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE;
            final String[] columns = {_id, album_name, artist, tracks,data,id1,tit,nam,typ};

            cursor = getContext().getContentResolver().query(uri, columns,null, null, null);
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()&&cursor.getCount()>0)
                do {
                    int x=cursor.getColumnCount();
                    System.out.println(x);
                    String id = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_id)));
                    String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(album_name));
                    String artist2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artist));
                    String nr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tracks));
            String data1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(data));
                String id2=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(id1));
                String title=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tit));
                String name1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(nam));
                String type=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(typ));
                    albumInfo s = new albumInfo(id, name, artist2, nr,data,id2,title,name1,type);
                    albumList.add(s);
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            recyclerView1.setAdapter(albumAdapter);
        }
```

> android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: data
>   (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, album, artist, numsongs,
>   duration, _id, title, _display_name, mime_type FROM album_info
>                                                                                   at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:179)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:135)
>                                                                                   at
>   android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:418)
>                                                                                   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:754)
>                                                                                   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:704)
>                                                                                   at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:662)
>                                                                                   at layout.BlankFragment.getAlbumsLists(BlankFragment.java:154)
>                                                                                   at layout.BlankFragment.onCreateView(BlankFragment.java:138)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short the column **_data** is not a column in the MediaStore.Audio.Albums nor are some other columns (see code). Rather I believe they may be from each track/song.

To get around the problems/issues BUT only get ALBUM data you can modify your code to :-

```
public void getAlbumsLists() {
    final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String _id = MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID;
    final String album_name = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ALBUM;
    final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.ARTIST;
    final String tracks = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Albums.NUMBER_OF_SONGS;
    //final String data=MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA; // NO
    final String id1=MediaStore.Audio.Albums._ID;
    final String tit=MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM; //NO
    final String nam=MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_KEY; // NO
    final String typ=MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE; // NO
    final String art=MediaStore.Audio.Albums.ALBUM_ART; //<<<< CAN GET
    final String artstkey = MediaStore.Audio.Artists.ARTIST_KEY; //<<<< CAN GET
    final String frstyr = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.FIRST_YEAR; //<<<< CAN GET
    final String lstyr = MediaStore.Audio.AlbumColumns.LAST_YEAR; //<<<< CAN GET
    final String artstid = "artist_id"; //<<<< CAN GET

    final String[] columns = {"*"};

    Cursor cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns,null, null, null);
    // Lists the columns in the cursor
    for (String s :cursor.getColumnNames()
         ) {
        Log.d("COLUMNS","Column = " +s);
    }
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        String id = (cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(_id)));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(album_name));
        String artist2 = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artist));
        String nr = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tracks));
        //String data1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(data)); //<<<< NOT A COLUMN
        String id2=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(id1));
        //String title=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(tit)); //<<<< NOT A COLUMN
        //String name1=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(nam)); //<<<< NOT A COLUMN
        //String type=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(typ)); //<<<< NOT A COLUMN
        // AVAIALABLE COLUMNS
        String artwork = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(art)); //<<<< ADDED
        String artistkey = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artstkey)); //<<<< ADDED
        String artistid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(artstid)); //<<<< ADDED
        String minyear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(frstyr));
        String maxyear = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(lstyr));
        albumInfo s = new albumInfo(id, name, artist2, nr,data,id2,title,name1,type); // EXCLUDED

            albumList.add(s); // EXCLUDED
        }
    cursor.close();
    recyclerView1.setAdapter(albumAdapter); // EXCLUDED
}
```

#### Notes

- Check for a null Cursor is futile a Cursor with no data will be empty (count = 0) not null.
- Added list of all columns in the extracted cursor
- Added available columns
- The above has been tested other lines with EXCLUDED comment.
- Changed query to get all rows i.e. instead of columns used **`*`**

  They are :-
- D/COLUMNS: Column = _id
- D/COLUMNS: Column = album
- D/COLUMNS: Column = album_key
- D/COLUMNS: Column = minyear
- D/COLUMNS: Column = maxyear
- D/COLUMNS: Column = artist
- D/COLUMNS: Column = artist_id
- D/COLUMNS: Column = artist_key
- D/COLUMNS: Column = numsongs
- D/COLUMNS: Column = album_art
- Finally you'll need to research on how to get the songs per album

### Extra - Getting Tracks :-

The following is what may get the tracks per album (see notes) :-

```
public void getSongsPerAlbum(String AlbumId) {
    final Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
    final String track_id = MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID;
    final String track_no = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TRACK;
    final String track_name = MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;
    final String artist = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST;
    final String duration = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DURATION;
    final String album = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM;
    final String albumid = MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM_ID;
    final String composer = MediaStore.Audio.Media.COMPOSER;
    final String year = MediaStore.Audio.Media.YEAR;
    final String path = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA;
    final String date_added = MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATE_ADDED;
    String[] columns = new String[]{
            track_id,
            track_no,
            track_name,
            artist,
            duration,
            album,
            albumid,
            composer,
            year,
            path,
            date_added
    };
    // Get all tracks if no album id
    Cursor csr;
    if (AlbumId == null || AlbumId.length() < 1) {
        csr = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns,null,null,track_no);
    } else {
        // Doesn't work think media has to be scanned first before albums are generated
        csr = this.getContentResolver().query(uri, columns,album + "=?",new String[]{AlbumId},track_no);
    }

    for (String s: csr.getColumnNames()
         ) {
        Log.d("SONGCOLUMN","Column = " + s);
    }
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        Log.d("SONG","Name of Song is " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(track_name)) +
                " from Album " + csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(album))
        );
    }
}
```

#### Notes

- Can pass null or "" and it will get all tracks (tested, results below)
- Again the above was tested in an activity and thus uses this for the context. You may need to change **`this`** to **`getActivity()`**.
- My external media is pretty limited and looks like :-

[image]

The resultant output is :-

```
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONGCOLUMN: Column = _id
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONGCOLUMN: Column = track
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONGCOLUMN: Column = title
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONGCOLUMN: Column = artist
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONGCOLUMN: Column = duration
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONGCOLUMN: Column = album
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONGCOLUMN: Column = album_id
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONGCOLUMN: Column = composer
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONGCOLUMN: Column = year
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONGCOLUMN: Column = _data
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONGCOLUMN: Column = date_added
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONG: Name of Song is Ride on time from Album Music
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONG: Name of Song is Modern Love from Album Let's Dance
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONG: Name of Song is China Girl from Album Let's Dance
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONG: Name of Song is Let's Dance from Album Let's Dance
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONG: Name of Song is Without You from Album Let's Dance
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONG: Name of Song is Ricochet from Album Let's Dance
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONG: Name of Song is Criminal World from Album Let's Dance
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONG: Name of Song is Cat People (Putting Out Fire) from Album Let's Dance
02-04 09:14:50.601 2799-2799/? D/SONG: Name of Song is Shake It from Album Let's Dance
```

Comment: Ooops just remembered ran the above in an activity so used this as the **context**, you'd likely need to replace **`this`** with **`getContext()`**.

Answer (score 0):

This probably might be so late but i hope it helps someone in future, i faced the same problem spent like a week trying to figure it out but actually it is very simple.
some music have only one column that has the song Title and the Artist name on one column so when use;

```
    cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST)
```

It will show an error saying that make sure your cursor is initialized properly,  trying to say the artist column does not exist
so u need only to use;

```
cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME))
```

i hope it helps someone as well. thanks